# What am I missing in this random number generator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a very simple piece of javascript that asks a user to pick a number between 1 and 10,000. The computer should then try and guess that number and display the number of attempts it took to guess correctly.

However, when I run it, it doesn't prompt the user or display any attempts. I'm probably missing something obvious and clear. Could someone give me some insight?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Guess the Number</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <script>
      var upper = 10000;
      var userPick = parseInt(prompt('Pick a number between 1 and 10,000'))
      var computerGuess = getRandomNumber(upper);
      var attempts = 0;

      function getRandomNumber(upper) {
          return Math.floor(Math.random()*upper) + 1;
      }

      while(computerGuess !== randomNumber){
          computerGuess = getRandomNumber(upper);
          attempts+=1;        
      }  
      document.write('<p>Your number was ' + randomNumber + '. The computer guessed this number after ' + attempts + ' attempts.</p>') 
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You saved the user entered number as `userPick` but use `randomNumber` everywhere else. You should be seeing the prompt, but after that it wont work since you used the wrong name. Check the console for errors

Comment: Thank you! I was moving things around so much I made my own problem without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to call the number the user inputs by a few different names. When you grab the user input you call it `userPick`, but in the while loop and the output you compare the computer generated number against `randomNumber` and not `userPick`.

To prevent the code from running when the user doesn't input anything the while loop and output should be surrounded with a check against [NaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN).

Here is the updated code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Guess the Number</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <script>
var upper = 10000;
var userPick = parseInt(prompt('Pick a number between 1 and 10,000'))
var computerGuess = getRandomNumber(upper);
var attempts = 0;

function getRandomNumber(upper) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*upper) + 1;
}

if(!isNaN(userPick)) {
  while(computerGuess !== userPick){
    attempts+=1;
    computerGuess = getRandomNumber(upper);
  }

  document.write('<p>Your number was ' + userPick + '. The computer guessed this number after ' + attempts + ' attempts.</p>')  
} else {
  document.write('<p>Invalid Input</p>')
}

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is an example of it running with 1-25: http://plnkr.co/edit/57iloqjWFQPifPluFkBu?p=preview

Comment: Thank you! I was moving things around so much I made my own problem without seeing it.